# Singleton pattern in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, singleton

I have an asp.net application. I am using singleton pattern to design my code. Looks like below…

```
public static class FactoryClass
    {
        private static Core obj = null;
        private static readonly object padLock = new object();
        public static Core GetInstance()
        {
            lock (padLock)
            {
                if (obj == null)
                {
                    obj = new Core();
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

This implementation is thread-safe. I want to know whether this implementation is correct or not, in the case of asp.net (multiple requests will share single instance). Please advice…

Comment: See also http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx

Comment: What exactly is your reason for making something a static singleton in asp.net? Is there something particularly expensive that this class will do?

Comment: Are you missing Private Constructor?

Comment: Just as a general comment, I would personally add another `if (obj == null)` around the lock itself. There's no point taking the hit of locking if it's already been instantiated. You still need the inner `if` so that it doesn't get created multiple times, but an outer one could bypass the entire process when not required.

Comment: You already know the most important thing: all requests share the same instance (and not "one per user" as sometimes is thought)

Comment: @HansKesting Already read the link.There they have used sealed class and a constructor.

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix i am not mentioning about threading.my doubt is that, because of single instance whether any data share problem will come or not(like static variable)

Comment: @ImranRizvi what is the use of using private contructor and sealed class in singleton pattern?

Comment: @HansKesting i know all users will share the same instance.My question come from that point.If all users have same instance,Will any data sharing issue occurs?(like using static variable)

Comment: @anish - when the users share the same instance, that means that the data *in* that instance (or referred to by that instance) is (also) shared.

Comment: Why are you using Factory class as static, a Factory is made for constructing more than one object you can make it Singleton without static class and , private constructor and public GetInstance method that returns an object of it if exists.

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix Yes,That's a good idea.My question is regarding multiple users sharing single instance.Will any data sharing issue occurs?(like using static variable)

Comment: @ImranRizvi In your answer too you have static class.Please give a good singleton design pattern which can be used in asp.net with out affecting multiple user requests with same data

Comment: You're still being unclear. Do you want users to share data or not? If you want something that lives for the lifetime of one request, use HttpContext.Items. If you want something that lives for the lifetime of one user session, use Session. If you want something that's common for all users on a single server, use static - but be prepared to handle all of the corresponding thread-related issues (many requests can access that data concurrently).

Answer (score 0):

You single ton object scope will be within app domain, that means all the sessions will use SingleTon object within that appdomain (bydefault).

A new object will be created only if you have a farm with different servers.

I prefer lock only when you need to construct an object, not when you've to return it. Following is the modified code:

```
public static class FactoryClass
{
    private static Core obj = null;
    private static readonly object padLock = new object();

    public static Core GetInstance()
    {
        lock (padLock)
        {
          if (obj == null)
          {
                obj = new Core();
          }
        }
        return obj;
      }
}
```

Comment: what is the use of using private contructor in singleton pattern?

Comment: I've changed the code, I got you need Single Core object not factory class.

Comment: this implementation is not thread safe as it does not ensure atomicity between the null test and the constructor call. You may have a look at http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx as pointed by @HansKesting

Comment: @ImranRizvi Ok.I want to know when we are using singleton pattern in asp.net will it cause any data mix up problem for users.user1 getting user2 data.Like static variables.Here are also we are using static member

Comment: @anish SingleTon here insures that object will be shared between multiple sessions within app-domain, thus if you return data (core) that is not user specific there will be a mix obviously.

Comment: @jbl yes that was a typo. modified it.

Comment: 'public class Core : InterfaceStore
    {
      public bool GetDetFromDB(string id)
        {
}
}
'My core look like this.I am not using any Core class level variables.i want know concurrent access cause any issue or not

Comment: as per my understanding , you are passing unique id for each user to the GetDetFromDB method, in this case there is no chance of data mix between two user's data, we've created single instance of Core class, it does not have to do with mixing of request/response of a method invocation.

Comment: @ImranRizvi which are the situations which will cause data mix up when we are using singleton pattern.One is static variable.any other?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42027/discussion-between-anish-and-imran-rizvi)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of data is being stored in the object of type Core. Say its some config data, which, you want to separately manage (i.e. its entirely different from those in the web.config) then it makes sense.

However, lets say, if the website is a shopping cart application...and you wish to store the user object like that...say the user object contains a list of items he has saved in the card. This will get stored in the appdomain. Hence it goes against your implementation. Because you'd want your user info tied to the incoming request rather than the whole application. Hence per request you'd need to query this at least once...(speaking in a traditional sense of course).

Continuing with the same example, imagine you want to use the user object this way: this user object is being used inside of different classes inside your web application. Traditionally people would write code to access the db and create the object every time you need to use the user object. Instead, you'd want some singleton-like pattern here. In this case, your user object will be queried (and created) from the db once, and re-used throughout the lifetime of the request. This is possible if you cache this object (post its creation) in the http context cache...i.e. `HttpContext.Current.Items["foo"]`

The following code explains the point...

```
public class AppUser
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string[] Roles { get; set; }

    public AppUser()
    {
        var appuser = HttpContext.Session["AppUser"] as AppUser;
        if(appuser == null)
            throw new Exception("User session has expired");
        Username = appuser.Username;
        Roles = appuser.Roles;
    }
}


public class WebAppContext
{
    const string ContextKey = "WebAppContext";

    WebAppContext() { } //empty constructor
    public static WebAppContext Current 
    {
        get
        {
            var ctx = HttpContext.Current.Items[ContextKey] as WebAppContext;
            if(ctx == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    ctx = new WebAppContext() { User = new AppUser() };
                }
                catch
                {
                    //Redirect for login
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(ContextKey, ctx);                     
            }       
            return ctx;     
        }
    }

    public AppUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Ps: taken from this post: [a request level singleton object in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18502493/145682)

Comment: @deostoll The code you mentioned is for single instance per user.I asked about multiple users accessing same instance

Comment: @anish I had given an example scenario of site wide config settings (which are entirely different from the ones in your web.config) in the beginning itself. Eg. of such a setting can be for e.g. the banner image of your website. The image path can be set in an application level variable (in your case a static variable)